# Mouse cursor is hiding until Item Selected from dropdown list

Tags: vb.net, winforms

VB.NET Winforms Application... When a user starts typing in the search box of the application it automatically populates the name list dropdown box with the valid results and sets the droppeddown value to true... Everything is working fine except the fact that the user is forced to select a value from the name list or press the esc key because without doing so the mouse cursor just disappears and you have to move the mouse all the way outside the application for it to come back and it will only do so while outside the applicaiton.. Below is the code that I am using for this and it should be noted that I am using the droppeddown value else where in the application and none of those instances have an issue its only this one... Any ideas???

```
     Private Sub u_lastName_Box_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles u_lastName_Box.TextChanged
    u_nameLook_Box.Items.Clear()
    Dim TenList As New List(Of tenant)
    Dim x As List(Of tenant) = db.tenants.Where(Function(f) f.last_name.Contains(u_lastName_Box.Text) AndAlso f.propertyId = selectedProperty).OrderBy(Function(f) f.last_name).ToList
    For Each _ten In x
        Dim c = _ten
        u_nameLook_Box.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(c.Occupantid) + " -- " + c.last_name + "," + c.first_name)
    Next

    RemoveHandler u_nameLook_Box.DropDown, AddressOf u_nameLook_Box_DropDown
    u_nameLook_Box.DroppedDown = True
    AddHandler u_nameLook_Box.DropDown, AddressOf u_nameLook_Box_DropDown
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually fixed this issue just now after thinking about it for the night.. I tried the cursor.show with no dice... I thought a little more on that and decided to set the cursor style prior to the cursor.show and it works now... My updated code is below... There is some question as to how or why the cursor style and visibilty got changed in the first place...

```
     Private Sub u_lastName_Box_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles u_lastName_Box.TextChanged
    u_nameLook_Box.Items.Clear()
    If Not u_lastName_Box.Text.Length < 1 Then
        Dim TenList As New List(Of tenant)
        Dim x As List(Of tenant) = db.tenants.Where(Function(f) f.last_name.Contains(u_lastName_Box.Text) AndAlso f.propertyId = selectedProperty).OrderBy(Function(f) f.last_name).ToList
        For Each _ten In x
            Dim c = _ten
            u_nameLook_Box.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(c.Occupantid) + " -- " + c.last_name + "," + c.first_name)
        Next


        RemoveHandler u_nameLook_Box.DropDown, AddressOf u_nameLook_Box_DropDown
        u_nameLook_Box.DroppedDown = True
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        Cursor.Show()
        AddHandler u_nameLook_Box.DropDown, AddressOf u_nameLook_Box_DropDown
    Else
        u_lookup_boxes_fill()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced same problem and I solved it "updating" mouse status,

```
ComboBoxClients.DroppedDown = True

Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
```